# Split Text Processor not splitting my input file

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an input text file the content of which is as below
:

11111111

22222222

33333333

44444444

55555555

I need 5 different files each containing one line from the input file.
For e.g. my first split file should have data as 111111. Second file should have data as 2222222. Third file should have data as 333333 and so on till fifth file.

My dataflow is : GetFile--> Split File --> Put File

The Split File processor has been configured with below properties:

Line Split Count : 1

Maximum Fragment SIze : 100kb

Header Line Count : 0

Remove Trailing Newlines: true

My PutFile Processor configuration are as below:

Directory: C:\Demo\Target

Conflict Resolution Strategy: Ignore

Create Missing Directories : True

The input file is getting copied to target directory without splitting. I tried changing the Conflict Resolution Strategy in Put File Processor but I am not getting the required output.

Can anyone please guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: From the SplitText processor, what relation is going to PutFile processor? Is the relation `split` or `original`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the `Maximum Fragment Size : 100kb` is not correctly set.
Use `100 KB` instead.

Syntax of *Maximum Fragment Size* should be `number`+`[space]`+`KB/MB/GB`